# Binding the multiple result set from store procedure into one list

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, stored-procedures

I am returning three multiple result set from stored procedures and binding into the three list(some limitation to return as a single reslt set). 
I want to make one final list which contains all the list data.

```
Ex :
Resultset1(OrderList)

Orderid customerid ordernumber ordername

Resultset2(CustomerList)

orderid customerid customernumber customername

Resultset3(OrderCustomerList)  
orderid customerid productname cost
```

assigning this result set into each list..

I want the final list like below, if the customer details is there for that order i want to bind the customer details else it will be like similarly 
for product details..

```
Final list

orderid : 1234,
customerid :as12,
ordernumber : 23456,
ordername : "xyz",
customerdetails : [{ "key" : "customernumber" "value" : 1234 },{ "key" : 
"customername" "value" : "abc" } ],
productdetails : [{ "key" : "productname" "value" : "west" },{ "key" : 
"cost" "value" : 90} ]
```

Currently doing with for each loop. First looping the order list and again loopong the customer and ordercustomerlist and checking whether 
that order contains customer and ordercustomer data or not. if it is there binding the data else making it as null.

Is there anyway to do this rather than foreach loop , because if it is 1000 records , 1000 times outer loop is going and inner loop also going 
many times and it is impacting the performance.

Comment: If you have an ORM like EF you don't need to do that, you only need to configure the DbContext to use stored procedures to load individual *entities*. What do your classes look like, what do the stored procedures do, why do you use stored procedures in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you get all results sets from database in single roundtrip call and your issue is not multiple database calls, instead performance of nested for loops and list lookups.

If this is true In that case you can convert orders and customers lists to dictionaries for fast lookups O(1) and then do single for loop over OrderCustomerList, and within that loop get required order or customer details from dictionary.

```
var orderDetails = result1.ToDictionary(order => order.orderid);
var customerDetails = result2.ToDictionary(customer => customer.customerid);
...
// get order by id.
var order = orderDetails[orderId];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the 3 list and select whatever you want:

```
var query = from order in Resultset1
            join cust in Resultset2
            on order.orderid equals cust.orderid && order.customerid equals cust.customerid 
           select new { cust.orderid, cust.customerid, cust.customernumber, cust.customername, order.ordernumber, order.ordername} into mid
           join ocl in Resultset3
            on mid.orderid equals ocl.orderid && mid.customerid equals ocl.customerid 
           select new {
               mid.orderid, 
               mid.customerid, 
               mid.customernumber, 
               mid.customername, 
               mid.ordernumber, 
               mid.ordername,
               ocl.productname 
}
```

if orderid is unique then you can join it like

```
on order.orderid equals cust.orderid
```

instead of

```
on order.orderid equals cust.orderid && order.customerid equals cust.customerid
```